# Make empty div background colour fill entire div vertically

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div inside a div and I want the inside div to either contain a background colour or background image. My code is:

```
<div class="row two">
    <div class="cols n15">
<h2 class="latestVideo">Latest Video</h2>
<iframe width="100%" height="370" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/a-XQL60NVmQ" frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

  <div class="cols n9 clearfix">
<h2>Other Videos</h2>
<div class="otherVids">
<p>"test"<p>
<!-- <img src="images/otherVideos.jpg" alt=""> -->
    <div class="video1">        
    </div>
    <div class="vidoe2">        
    </div>
    <div class="video3">        
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Right now this makes it look like this:

[image]

What I want is for the red box to extend all way down and match the height of the div on the left side. I realize that this would work if I have the div(otherVids) a height and width, but if I do this the website won't be responsive anymore.

So if there anyway to make the div background fill up the empty space while still remaining responsive?

Here is the CSS code I have:

```
  .otherVids{
  background-image: url('images/otherVideos.jpg');
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the height of `otherVids` to be equal to the `iframe`.

Add `height:370px;` to the css of `.otherVids`

Comment: This works, I should have just done this because the iframe height never changes only the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two method,the first thing is:

```
.otherVids{
  min-height:370px;
}
```

or:

```
.otherVids{
  height:370px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

if your video list is to many,you need to design the content responsive.

finally,I think you don't need use `width:100%`,because div is block element.